# Creating a csv file, not adding to the next column

Tags: c#, csv

First time trying to build a csv file in c#, here is the code:

```
string FilePath = @"C:\Users\me\Downloads\csvfiles\test-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".csv";
string delimit = ",";
List<string> cells = new List<string>();

Console.WriteLine("Gathering the data...");

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM contacts";

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Console.WriteLine("Building the csv file");

while (reader.Read())
{
    AddCell((IDataRecord)reader, cells);
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimit, cells[i]));
}

File.WriteAllText(FilePath, sb.ToString());

/*Method to add each record to the list*/
public static void AddCell(IDataRecord record, List<string> cells)
{
    cells.Add(record[0].ToString());
    cells.Add(record[1].ToString());
}
```

Trouble is, it appends everything to a new row, it doesn't move record[1] to the next column and start a new row...

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: I am joining by the delimit variable, which is why it is moving to the next row...

Comment: If you discovered a solution to your problem, post it as an answer, please. Or delete your question completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your For loop is incorrect for what you are trying to do.

Replace :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
    {
         sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimit, cells[i]));
    }
```

With

```
    int i = 0;
    while (i < cells.Count)
    {
       sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimit, cells[i],cells[i+1]));
       i = i + 2;
    }
```

Comment: @user2405469 : If this solved your problem, please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
string FilePath = @"C:\Users\me\Downloads\csvfiles\test-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".csv";
string delimit = ",";
List<string> cells = new List<string>();

Console.WriteLine("Gathering the data...");

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT id, name FROM contacts";

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Console.WriteLine("Building the csv file");

while (reader.Read())
{
    AddCell((IDataRecord)reader, cells);
}

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
{
    if (cells[i].Equals("\n"))
    {
        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append(cells[i]);
    }
}

File.WriteAllText(FilePath, sb.ToString());

/*Method to add each record to the list*/
public static void AddCell(IDataRecord record, List<string> cells)
{
    cells.Add(record[0].ToString());
    cells.Add(",");
    cells.Add(record[1].ToString());
    cells.Add("\n");
}
```

not as elegant as yours @cvraman but it worked too :) I will be using your solution.